# how to display a 3d model with jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, 3d, android-jetpack-compose, sceneform, 3d-model

I want to show a 3d object in app, that you can see all sides of that with rotating in `jetpack` compose and I can't find a source code.

Can anyone show the codes of making it please?

I read something about `sceneform` but there was no documentation or library for `jetpack` compose.

this is what I found:

```
@Composable
fun MySceneformView(model: Model) {
    SceneformModel(
        model = model,
        scale = 1.0f,
        rotation = Quaternion.identity(),
        position = Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
    )
}
```

and I don't know if it's work.